# How to check using WatiN that a certain URL is served?

Tags: watin

I want to make sure that when the user clicks a button he is redirected to a certain page. I am not sure how I can use watiN to see if the page is served or not.

`IE.Current.Url` shows the url of the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

Form a quick search, IE.LocationURL should give you what you need.